# check value for multiple array in loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i have three array `sure[]`,`maybe[]` and `notify[]` that are displaying in a loop like this:

```
sure[0]     maybe[0]     notify[0]
sure[1]     maybe[1]     notify[1]
sure[2]     maybe[2]     notify[2]
sure[3]     maybe[3]     notify[3]
```

And so on...

Now what I want that is in form post I get all arrays and there should be minimum one value of `sure[0]` or `maybe[0]` or `notify[0]` true or checked means horizontally`.

In this process will be same for all next rows and each row must contain minimum one true or checked value although can all selected or checked.

I am trying to solve this problem from past three days .
How can I do this please check it and give me idea.

thanks in advance

Comment: Gonna need you to post some code. Not sure what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether at least one of the three is set by doing this:

```
$oneSet = $sure[0] || $maybe[0] || $notify[0];
```

If you want to do this in a loop, you can do something like this (assuming each list is equally long)

```
$oneSetInEach = true;
for( $i = 0 ; $i < count($sure) ; $i++ ) {
  $thisSet = $sure[$i] || $maybe[$i] || $notify[$i]; // check if one is set here
  $oneSetInEach = $oneSetInEach && $thisSet; // if all the previous ones are ok, and this is ok, we are still ok
}

// $oneSetInEach will now be true or false depending on whether each row has at least 1 element set.
```

Comment: thank for reply ....but did the same as you but it is not the solution.how can i keep record which horizontal row is returning true value and which one false

Comment: Hi Erik it is working in some cases but what if i select all notify[0],notify[1],notify[2] and notify[3] then it should return true but in this case it returning false to me......now what should done..

Answer (score 0):

If all array count() are same

```
       <?php

$i = 0;
while ($i < count($sure)) {
    if ((isset($sure[$i]) AND $sure[$i] == true) OR ( isset($maybe[$i]) AND $maybe[$i] == true) OR ( isset($notify[$i]) AND $notify[$i] == true)) {
        // your code  
    }

    $i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
$res = true;
for( $i=0 ; $i<count($sure) ; $i++ ) {
  $res &= $sure[$i]  || $maybe[$i] || $notify[$i];
}
```